# How to hide the textLabel property of the default UITableViewCell from all UITableView rows?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uiscrollviewdelegate

I am playing with some UITableView coding and tried to hide the default textLabel property. I used the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol and used both -scrollViewDidScroll and scrollViewDidEndDecelerating methods to hide and show the label.

The code works fine just with the first row of the table and not all of them which is what I want. Here's my code:

*Edited to show the solution code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   cell.textLabel.hidden = NO;
   cell.textLabel.text = @"TEST";

   return cell;
}

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    for (cell in [self.tableView visibleCells]) {
    cell.textLabel.hidden = YES;
  }
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    for (cell in [self.tableView visibleCells]) {
    cell.textLabel.hidden = NO;
  }
}
```

So anyone could help me to hide and show all the rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've tried declaring your `cell` as a variable in your table view controller or as a global somewhere. That's not going to work because it will always be set to whatever the last cell dequeued was. You should definitely declare that as locally in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Hiding the `textLabel` in `scollViewDidScroll` and showing it again in `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` should work fine, you just have to make sure you're hiding/showing all the currently visible cells in the table. Luckily, there's a method of `tableView` that'll help with that: `visibleCells`. That returns an `NSArray` of `UITableViewCell`s which you can loop over and hide the `textLabel`.

So, it should look something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDate *object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [object description];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return cell;
}

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    for (UITableViewCell *cell in [self.tableView visibleCells]) {
        cell.textLabel.hidden = YES;
    }
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    for (UITableViewCell *cell in [self.tableView visibleCells]) {
        cell.textLabel.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did declare cell globally. I fixed this and declared locally and also modified the scrollView methods, but still didn't work. All textLabels are still visible all the time.

Comment: Hey I managed to get it work just modifying form both scrollView methods [tableView visibleCells] to [self.tableView visibleCells] and added cell.textLabel.hidden = NO; to cellForRowAtIndexPath and all worked fine!!!! Thanks!!!

Comment: Opps, that was an error on my part not putting `self.` in there; I fixed the code in the answer. Glad you found it and fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this `cell.textLabel.hidden = YES;`in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.  that is where each cell is created.

Comment: If I do that all textLabels will be hidden without scrolling. I need them showing while static, but when the user scrolls the table only then the labels hide and when is finished scrolling the labels will be back again.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** This is just one possible solution, There might be other, more optimized solutions out there.

- Get the visible cells from your table each time the table begins scrolling with `scrollViewDidScroll:`. Then iterate over each cell and set it's `textLabel` hidden.
- Get the visible cells in `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` and set the `textLabel` visible.

Get the visible cells with `yourTableView.visibleCells`.

Comment: I saw Mike's answer after posting mine. Same solution. You should try with it.